# R: creating a loop with an increasing value of 0.1

Tags: r, for-loop

I would like to create a loop that increases the variable by 0.1 and writes it to a variable.
From 0.10 to 1. jump every 0.10

```
x <- c(1:10)
for (i in x)
{
  a = 0.1
  y <- a+0.1

  print(y)

}
```

Comment: more simple: y <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)

Comment: Also `seq_len(10) / 10` or similarly `seq(10) / 10`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use [seq](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/seq) function (take a look at the link for documentation)

```
number_sequence = seq(0.1,1,0.1)
for (i in number_sequence)
{
  print(i) 
}
```

in `seq(from,to,by)` we have

- from, to: the starting and (maximal) end values of the sequence. Of
  length 1 unless just from is supplied as an unnamed argument.
- by: number, increment of the sequence.

Comment: @Alaeh A, note that you don't save your `print`

Comment: The code in the question actually hasn't saved the sequence so I assumed only printing it is needed, I edited my answer though. tnx

Answer (score 0):

You built your `loop` incorrectly.

When building a `loop`, the `for` part needs to include 3 argument: the counter (i), start index (the number before the `:`), end index (the number after the `:`). And between the `{}` comes what ever function(s)/adjustment/etc. you want to do.

Some possible variations for your `loop` are like this:

```
y <- 0
jumpBy <- 0.1
for (i in 1:10) {

  y <- y + jumpBy

  print(y)

}
```

Or like this, using the `seq_along()` function (generally speaking, using `seq_along()` is said to be better than using `seq()` in this context):

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 0
jumpBy <- 0.1
for (i in seq_along(x)) {

  y <- y + jumpBy

  print(y)

}
```

However, you should probably do as @Mislav said:

```
y <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
```

The reason to use `seq()` and it's variations over a `loop` is because it's less time consuming, less resourceful and the chances for bugs are lower.

For example, if we would benchmark the `loop`s and `seq()`, we can see that using `seq()` was about 3 (or 5) times faster than using a `loop`:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(
  "for_loop" = {
    dy <- 0
    jumpBy <- 0.1
    for (i in 1:10) {
       y <- y + jumpBy
     } }, 
  "for_loop_seq_along" = {
    x <- 1:10
    y <- 0
    jumpBy <- 0.1
    for (i in seq_along(x)) {
       y <- y + jumpBy
    }}, 
  "Seq" = {
    y <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
  },
  replications = 1000, 
  columns = c(
    "test", "replications", "elapsed"))

                test replications elapsed
1           for_loop         1000    3.22
2 for_loop_seq_along         1000    5.00
3                Seq         1000    0.07
```